# Showing Lipschitz continuity from gradient

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I found a lemma showing Lipschitz continuity by bounded gradient and I am a bit confused.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow[0,1]$. The text states:

> It suffices to show that $u \cdot \nabla f(x)$ is bounded for any unit
> direction $u$.

I assume they mean $||u||=1$ when saying "unit direction". To my understanding the optimal Lipschitz constant is given by $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}||\nabla f(x)||$. However, I do not get their argument of multiplying the gradient with $u$.

Comment: of course that $\sup_{x\in[0,1]}$ should be $\sup_{x\in\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: What is the _directional derivative_ $D_uf$ in terms of $u$ and $\nabla f$?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So the argument is: if for all unit vectors $u$, $u^T \nabla f(x)$ is bounded, i.e. $\max_{||u||=1} u^T \nabla f(x)= ||\nabla f(x)||<L$, it implies the norm of the gradient is bound at $x$ and thus $f$ is $L$-Lipschitz in the neighbourhood of $x$. If we then show that this is true for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, then we have Lipschitzness everywhere?